# Turn scroll bar ''offline'' instead of 'overflow:hidden' while opening a modal

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, overflow

I'm making a website with modals and I was wondering, could you turn the scroll bar 'offline' (leave the scroll bar in place even though the page is not scrollable) instead of overflow: hidden?

Now I use this:
When I open a modal, I add a class to the body en when I close this modal, I delete this.

```
$('body').addClass('modal-open');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
```

My CSS is looking like this:

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But by doing this, my body content is moving to the right (because the scrollbar disappears first, and then my modal opens).

Putting the addClass code after opening the modal doesn't work. Maybe someone has suggestions to look it better?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "offline".

Comment: I think he means leave the scroll bar in place even though the page is not scrollable.

Comment: To the background so it doesn't work until you close the modal

Comment: what happens if you don't add overflow:hidden to the modal?

Comment: Then the scrollbar from the body is overruling the scrollbar from the modal